# Is there a best way to create a custom user model and extend to Profile for production in django? Because I keep getting these error in production

Tags: python, django, authentication, heroku, profile

Hi can anyone please highlight the best way to extend a custom user model to a profile or explain what I am doing wrong. I created a custom user model, and extended it to a profile app which all works fine and passes in development. However in production on heroku I kept running into server errors when I click on profile, so I turned debug to True and it saw this traceback;

```
ProgrammingError at /u/profile/
can't adapt type 'MyUser'
```

So I figured, hey probably it's complaining about passing in the whole model instead of the object in the model. However, the filter in my views specifies the object been retrieved be the object related to the requested user. Here's my view below:

```
User = get_user_model()

class ProfileUserView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
           user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user)
           post_list = Post.objects.filter(author__username__iexact=user).order_by('-submission_time')
           paginator = Paginator(post_list, 10)
           page = request.GET.get('page')

           try:
                post = paginator.page(page)
           except PageNotAnInteger:
                post = paginator.page(1)
           except EmptyPage:
                post = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
           profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
           template = 'profiles/profile_user.html'
           context = {
                    'profile': profile,
                    'post': post
                   }
           return render(request, template, context)
        else:
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account_login'))
```

Any help/explanation with regards to what I am doing wrong with retrieving associated data from the profile model by extending a custom user model will be greatly appreciated.

Here's the profile model block;

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Beginner")
```

Here's the full traceback

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://sustenergy.herokuapp.com/u/profile/

Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in validate_number
  41.             number = int(number)

During handling of the above exception (int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'), another exception occurred:

File "/app/profiles/views.py" in get
  37.                 post = paginator.page(page)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in page
  57.         number = self.validate_number(number)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in validate_number
  43.             raise PageNotAnInteger(_('That page number is not an integer'))

During handling of the above exception (That page number is not an integer), another exception occurred:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (can't adapt type 'MyUser') was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/profiles/views.py" in get
  39.                 post = paginator.page(1)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in page
  57.         number = self.validate_number(number)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in validate_number
  46.         if number > self.num_pages:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in **get**
  35.         res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in num_pages
  91.         if self.count == 0 and not self.allow_empty_first_page:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in **get**
  35.         res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py" in count
  79.             return self.object_list.count()

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in count
  364.         return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_count
  499.         number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in get_aggregation
  480.         result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  886.             raise original_exception

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  876.             cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  80.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in **exit**
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /u/profile/
Exception Value: can't adapt type 'MyUser'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes needed in the lines,

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)
                                                    #^^^^^^^^^^
post_list = Post.objects.filter(author__username__iexact=user.username).order_by('-submission_time')
                                                              #^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that worked, can't believe it never occurred to me to pass the username argument. I feel a bit dumb right now...

Comment: Would you please, then do me a favour and tag the answer as selected?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit AbstractBaseUser django builtin model in your custom model and make required field in model. check below django example of custom user model

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I just didn't paste that part of the code.

Comment: Did I mention this works perfectly in development(locally), plus passed test but gives that error in Heroku production.

Comment: I turned debug to True when I was getting 500 internal error, and I got this:                                                                                                         ProgrammingError at /u/profile/
can't adapt type 'MyUser'

Comment: Just added it below

Comment: Jst added it above